# I'm having some trouble while solving Google's foobar challenge.I'm at level 4 and I'm not getting how did we get the path matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, graph-theory

I don't want any code.Just explain me the question (**Especially the path matrix**).Here is the question  :

You and your rescued bunny prisoners need to get out of this collapsing death trap of a space station - and fast! Unfortunately, some of the bunnies have been weakened by their long imprisonment and can't run very fast. Their friends are trying to help them, but this escape would go a lot faster if you also pitched in. The defensive bulkhead doors have begun to close, and if you don't make it through in time, you'll be trapped! You need to grab as many bunnies as you can and get through the bulkheads before they close.

The time it takes to move from your starting point to all of the bunnies and to the bulkhead will be given to you in a square matrix of integers. Each row will tell you the time it takes to get to the start, first bunny, second bunny, ..., last bunny, and the bulkhead in that order. The order of the rows follows the same pattern (start, each bunny, bulkhead). The bunnies can jump into your arms, so picking them up is instantaneous, and arriving at the bulkhead at the same time as it seals still allows for a successful, if dramatic, escape. (Don't worry, any bunnies you don't pick up will be able to escape with you since they no longer have to carry the ones you did pick up.) You can revisit different spots if you wish, and moving to the bulkhead doesn't mean you have to immediately leave - you can move to and from the bulkhead to pick up additional bunnies if time permits.

In addition to spending time traveling between bunnies, some paths interact with the space station's security checkpoints and add time back to the clock. Adding time to the clock will delay the closing of the bulkhead doors, and if the time goes back up to 0 or a positive number after the doors have already closed, it triggers the bulkhead to reopen. Therefore, it might be possible to walk in a circle and keep gaining time: that is, each time a path is traversed, the same amount of time is used or added.

Write a function of the form answer(times, time_limit) to calculate the most bunnies you can pick up and which bunnies they are, while still escaping through the bulkhead before the doors close for good. If there are multiple sets of bunnies of the same size, return the set of bunnies with the lowest prisoner IDs (as indexes) in sorted order. The bunnies are represented as a sorted list by prisoner ID, with the first bunny being 0. There are at most 5 bunnies, and time_limit is a non-negative integer that is at most 999.

For instance, in the case of

```
[
  [0, 2, 2, 2, -1],  # 0 = Start
  [9, 0, 2, 2, -1],  # 1 = Bunny 0
  [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],  # 2 = Bunny 1
  [9, 3, 2, 0, -1],  # 3 = Bunny 2
  [9, 3, 2, 2,  0],  # 4 = Bulkhead
]
```

and a time limit of 1, the five inner array rows designate the starting point, bunny 0, bunny 1, bunny 2, and the bulkhead door exit respectively. You could take the path:

```
Start End Delta Time Status
    -   0     -    1 Bulkhead initially open
    0   4    -1    2
    4   2     2    0
    2   4    -1    1
    4   3     2   -1 Bulkhead closes
    3   4    -1    0 Bulkhead reopens; you and the bunnies exit
```

With this solution, you would pick up bunnies 1 and 2. This is the best combination for this space station hallway, so the answer is [1, 2].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's model the problem using graph theory. The position of each interest point (start, each bunny, bulkhead) can be thought of as a vertex. The direct path from each of these points to another will be a weighted edge in the graph.

As you can see, we have a dense graph here as there is a direct path that connects any two interest points directly.

The matrix is just telling you the relative cost in time to the bulkhead closure (a path can have a negative weight if it adds more time before closure of the bulkhead than the actual time required to walk it). It means it is the **adjacency matrix** modeling the graph we defined above.

As such, each row of the matrix represents the paths from one point to another:

- First row is always the starting point. It tells you the impact on the closure time to go from the starting point to any other point (bunnies, bulkhead)
- Then come the rows for the bunnies, the second row in  your example tells you the time impact to go from the position of bunny #0 to any other point and so on.
- Finally you have the paths from the bulkhead to the other points

Some hints to solve the problem:

- If there is a negative cycle in the graph, you can escape with all the bunnies and since you are only required to return the set of rescued bunnies... You can exit as soon as a negative cycle is detected!
- If there isn't, then you'ld better think about *Bellman-Ford* and see where this leads you (good thing *Bellman-Ford* algorithm can also be used to detect negative cycles!)

---

**EDIT: Expliciting the logic behind the matrix**

To see how it works let's unroll the given example:

```
time_limit = 1
times = [
    [0, 2, 2, 2, -1],  # 0 = Start
    [9, 0, 2, 2, -1],  # 1 = Bunny 0
    [9, 3, 0, 2, -1],  # 2 = Bunny 1
    [9, 3, 2, 0, -1],  # 3 = Bunny 2
    [9, 3, 2, 2,  0],  # 4 = Bulkhead
]
```

The deltas are simply coming from the relevant matrix coefficients. Each time you walk a path with a given `delta`, you have to update the `time_limit` accordingly:

```
delta = times[starting_point][ending_point]
time_limit = time_limit - delta
```

If the `time_limit` becomes strictly negative, the bulkhead closes. If it gets back up to zero (going through negative paths), it reopens. The question asks you to find the path to take to save the most bunnies and escape with them. This means that such a path must end in bulkhead with `time_limit >= 0`.

Let's walk through the example and explicit the deltas and the `time_limit` updates.
The best scenario is to walk the following path (the deltas simply come from the matrix coefficients):

- Start --> Bulkhead: cost is `time[0][4] # == -1` so `time_limit = 1 - (-1) = 2`
- Bulkhead --> Bunny #1: cost is `time[4][2] # == 2` so `time_limit = 2 - 2 = 0`
- Bunny #1 --> Bulkhead: cost is `time[2][4] # == -1` so `time_limit = 0 - (-1) = 1` (Bunny #1 escapes)
- Bulkhead --> Bunny #2: cost is `time[4][3] # == 2` so `time_limit = 1 - 2 = -1` (Bulkhead closes because `time_limit` became negative)
- Bunny #2 --> Bulkhead: cost is `time[3][4] # == -1` so `time_limit = -1 - (-1) = 0`  (Bulkhead reopens, you escape with Bunny #2)

The set of rescued bunny is thus `[1, 2]` (Bunny #1 and Bunny #2 ID's, sorted in ascending order as requested per the problem description).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: But how do we find the delta time end time and how come starting time is null?

Comment: @JINTUKUMARDAS Edited my answer to be more exhaustive. Hope this will help

Comment: can you help me with this 
Inputs:
(int) times = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
(int) time_limit = 3
 @Rerito